# calculate price across dataframes for different price types - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

for a project I'm doing I currently have 3 dataframes. These are for products, customers and orders. A simple version of these can be found below, the actual order frame has around 10.000 columns. The situation is the following: products have different price categories, and every customer has a special price for each of those categories. I currently have an order dataframe with order- customer, and product numbers, the amount of the ordered product and the date.

I would now like to add the order's price in a new column in the order dataframe. I managed to get the product's category in there, but I didn't know how to go from there or if even was the right way to go. Any help would be appreciated, below the dataframe pictures I included the code to make these sample dataframes.

df_products:

[image: df_products]

df_customers:

[image: df_customers]

df_orders:

[image: df_orders]

Code to create the dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd 

df_products = pd.DataFrame({'product_number': [1, 2, 3], 'product': ['product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3' ], 'price_type': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']})

df_customers = pd.DataFrame({'customer_number': [1, 2, 3], 'customer': ['customer 1', 'customer 2', 'customer 3' ], 'price_x': [7.50, 10.50, 12.50], 'price_y': [6.50, 9.20, 11.30], 'price_z': [8.50, 10.10, 13.40]})

df_orders = pd.DataFrame({'order_number': [1, 2, 3], 'date': ['19-03-2020', '19-03-2020', '20-03-2020' ], 'customer_number': [1, 3, 2], 'product_number': [1, 2, 3], 'amount': [1, 2, 2]})
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframes are the same length, you can simply add a new column.  Below I add a new column 'price' to df_orders and populate it with values from df_customers['price_y'].

Like this,

```
df_orders['price']=df_customers['price_y']
```

and the results are,

```
df_orders.head()



order_number    date    customer_number     product_number  amount  price
0   1   19-03-2020  1   1   1   6.5
1   2   19-03-2020  3   2   2   9.2
2   3   20-03-2020  2   3   2   11.3
```

Comment: they're not the same length, but that also doesn't work because not all products have price type Y

Comment: I used price_y as an example because you didn't specify which price you wanted in the order dataframe. I see that customers and orders have different columns and the customer column is different.  Try pd.melt